# How to write (simple) macro?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, clos

I need to write a macro `(with-hooks (monster method who what) &body body)` for a game I'm writing. Monster is a CLOS object, method and who are strings and what is a function (#' notation). The macroexpansion would be something to the effect of

```
(add-hook monster method who what)
,@body
(remove-hook monster method who)
```

I have **absolutely** no idea how to write such a macro, and I would appreciate some help.
I have the creepy feeling that this is easy and I'm a bit ignorant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
(defmacro with-hooks ((monster method who what) &body body)
  (let ((monster-var (gensym))
        (method-var (gensym))
        (who-var (gensym))
        (what-var (gensym)))
    `(let ((,monster-var ,monster) ; dummy comment
           (,method-var ,method)
           (,who-var ,who)
           (,what-var ,what))
        (add-hook ,monster-var ,method-var ,who-var ,what-var)
        (unwind-protect
           (progn ,@body)
          (remove-hook ,monster-var ,method-var ,who-var)))))
```

Some notes:

1. `something-var`s are used to ensure that expressions for `monster`, `method`, `who`, `what` are evaluated only once (because these expressions are referenced multiple times in macro body) and in left-to-right order.
2. `gensym`s are used to ensure that variables have guaranteed unique names
3. unwind-protect is used to ensure that `remove-hook` is called even in case of non-local exits (e.g., stack unwind due to exception being thrown).

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on a GPL roguelike game called Menace of the Mines (http://motm.sourceforge.net) and just want to make sure this being in there is OK with you. (I have an attributing comment (It's been there for a while))

Comment: I don't mind if you include this macro in any project in any way.